# How to run my WCF web Service on IIS 7.5 server?

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

Just finish to develop my WCF service. 
I have machine on my network that have windows server 2008 - and i want to run my wcf web service on this machine.

1. What files i need to copy from my project developing folder to the server machine ?
2. What i need to configur on the server machine ( IIS ) to have the ability to connect to the service from the client that run in the same network ?

Comment: This question seems more adapted to http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see **[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx)**

I don't think there are any changes in IIS 7.5 that would prevent you from following those steps.